# How to get value from a map using a function parameter as the key

Tags: elixir

```rb
def mapdna(dna) do
  dnarna = %{"G" => "C","C" => "G","T" => "A", "A" => "U"}
  dnarna[dna]
end
```

When I pass "G" to mapdna it should return "C"

Comment: Does that not work?

Comment: ```dnarna = %{"G" => "C","C" => "G","T" => "A", "A" => "U"}
%{"A" => "U", "C" => "G", "G" => "C", "T" => "A"}
iex(2)> dnarna["G"]
"C"```

It returns C.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
defmodule My do

  def mapdna(dna) 
  when is_binary(dna) do
    %{"G" => "C","C" => "G","T" => "A", "A" => "U"}[dna]
  end

end

#IO.puts My.mapdna(:G)
IO.puts My.mapdna("G")
```

In elixir, to test whether an argument is a string you use `is_binary/1`.

Running the code:

```
$ elixir my.exs
C
```

But, if I uncomment the commented line:

```
$ elixir my.exs
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in My.mapdna/1    

    The following arguments were given to My.mapdna/1:

        # 1
        :G

    my.exs:3: My.mapdna/1
    my.exs:12: (file)
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:677: Code.require_file/2
```

**Response to comment:**

Take a look at this code:

```
defmodule RNATranscription do 

  @rna_for  %{"G" => "C","C" => "G","T" => "A", "A" => "U"} 

  def to_rna(dna) do  
    String.codepoints(dna)
    |> Enum.map( &(@rna_for[&1]) )
    |> :erlang.list_to_binary
  end 
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.ex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> RNATranscription.to_rna "ACGT" 
"UGCA"

iex(2)>
```

The solution above won't be very efficient for REALLY long DNA strings (it splits the string into a list, then traverses the resulting list converting the values, then traverses the list yet again to join everything together).  For long DNA strings, you can use `binary pattern matching` to get each letter in the DNA string and build the RNA string as you go along.  According to the [erlang docs on binaries](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html), the following solution should be a highly optimized way to build the RNA string--even though you are adding to the "tail" of the RNA string:

```
defmodule RNATranscription do 

  @rna_for  %{"G" => "C","C" => "G","T" => "A", "A" => "U"} 

  def to_rna(dna) do  
    _to_rna(dna, <<>>)  #The second arg will hold the rna string as it's being built
  end 

  defp _to_rna(<<dna_letter::utf8, rest::binary>>, rna_string) do
    rna_letter = @rna_for[<<dna_letter::utf8>>] 
    _to_rna(rest, <<rna_string::binary, rna_letter::binary>>)
  end
  defp _to_rna(<<>>, rna), do: rna 

end
```

Note that `dna_letter` ends up being a codepoint(integer), and it must be converted back to a binary(string) with `<<....>>` for lookup in the map.  When matching binaries, you can't use a pattern like this:

```
<<dna_letter::binary, rest::binary>>
```

because the `::binary` type has a default size that is "the rest of the binary that you are trying to match" (although you can explicitly specify a size). As a result, `::binary` without a size can only appear once in a pattern, and it must be at the end of the pattern.  (On the other hand, the default size for `::utf8` is all the bytes that make up one utf8 codepoint, which is a maximum of 4 bytes).

Now, because your DNA letters are all ascii letters, i.e. always 1 byte long, you can also match the DNA strings using this pattern:

```
<dna_letter::binary-size(1), rest::binary>>
```

The first segment in the pattern explicitly sets a size on the `binary` type, so it will only match one byte, and dna_letter will end up being a binary(string), which means you won't have to convert a codepoint to a string for lookup in the map.  Here is the new pattern added to the solution:

```
defmodule RNATranscription do 

  @rna_for  %{"G" => "C","C" => "G","T" => "A", "A" => "U"} 

  def to_rna(dna) do  
    _to_rna(dna, <<>>)  #The second arg will hold the rna string as it's being built
  end 

  defp _to_rna(<<dna_letter::binary-size(1), rest::binary>>, rna_string) do
    rna_letter = @rna_for[dna_letter] 
    _to_rna(rest, <<rna_string::binary, rna_letter::binary>>)
  end
  defp _to_rna(<<>>, rna), do: rna 

end
```

I wonder if the line:

```
_to_rna(rest, <<acc::binary, rna::binary>>)
```

is equivalent to:

```
_to_rna(rest, acc <> rna)
```

??  If it is, the code can employ a few more elixir idioms:

```
defmodule RNATranscription do 

  @rna_for  %{"G" => "C","C" => "G","T" => "A", "A" => "U"} 

  def to_rna(dna) do  
    _to_rna(dna, "")  #The second arg will hold the rna string as it's being built
  end 

  defp _to_rna(<<dna_letter::binary-size(1)>> <> rest, rna_string) do
    rna_letter = @rna_for[dna_letter]
    _to_rna(rest, rna_string <> rna_letter)
  end
  defp _to_rna("", rna_string), do: rna_string

end
```

Comment: I am trying to get RNATranscription.to_rna('ACGT') to output 'UGCA'              
defmodule RNATranscription do
  def to_rna(dna) do
    dnarna = %{'G' => 'C','C' => 'G','T' => 'A', 'A' => 'U'}
    Enum.map(dna,&(dnarna[&1]))
  end
end

Comment: @DavidKurtz, Don't write code in comments.  Instead, write: "See the edits to my question.", then edit your question and add any code that you want me to take a look at.

Comment: @DavidKurtz, See my response to your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok found the answer

dnarna = %{?G => ?C,?C => ?G,?T => ?A, ?A => ?U}